# Rendering to (or reading from?) framebuffer doesn't work in mobile Safari

Tags: webgl, mobile-safari, framebuffer

For some reason, rendering to framebuffer and then from the buffer to screen doesn't seem to work on mobile Safari.  I had no opportunity to check out desktop Safari, but my Firefox renders the Microsoft logo fine, on my phone I just see the border:

```js
const dmnsn = [800, 600],
  glCtx = twgl.getContext(document.createElement("canvas")),
  imgLc =
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b6/Microsoft_logo_%281987%29.svg";
var bfInf = twgl.primitives.createXYQuadBufferInfo(glCtx),
  pgInf = twgl.createProgramInfo(glCtx, ["vs", "fs"]),
  imgTx = twgl.createTexture(glCtx, { src: imgLc }, tstSB),
  scnBf = twgl.createFramebufferInfo(glCtx, [{ wrap: glCtx.REPEAT}],dmnsn[0],dmnsn[1]);

function plcCv() {
  document.body.append(glCtx.canvas);
  glCtx.canvas.width = dmnsn[0];
  glCtx.canvas.height = dmnsn[1];
}
function drwTx(tx, fbi, fy) {
  twgl.bindFramebufferInfo(glCtx, fbi);
  twgl.drawObjectList(glCtx, [
    {
      programInfo: pgInf,
      bufferInfo: bfInf,
      uniforms: { u_texture: tx, u_flipy: fy }
    }
  ]);
}
function tstSB() {
  plcCv();
  drwTx(imgTx, scnBf, true);
  drwTx(scnBf.attachments[0], null, false);
}
```

```css
html{
  height:100%;
}
body{
  margin:0;
  height:100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
canvas{
  border-style:solid;
}
```

```html
<script id="vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
  
  attribute vec4 position;
  attribute vec2 texcoord;
    
  uniform bool u_flipy;
  
  varying vec2 v_texcoord;

  void main() {
    if(u_flipy) {
      v_texcoord = vec2(texcoord.x, 1.0 - texcoord.y);
    } else {
      v_texcoord = texcoord;
    }
    gl_Position = position;
  }
</script>
<script id="fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

varying vec2 v_texcoord;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main() {
  gl_FragColor=texture2D(u_texture,v_texcoord);
}
</script>
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
```

I'm aware that drawing SVGs is somewhat experimental, but that seemed to work just fine also on mobile Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the errors in Safari I see

> WebGL: drawElements: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering or is not 'texture complete', or it is a float/half-float type with linear filtering and without the relevant float/half-float linear extension enabled.

To figure out which texture was the issue used [webgl-lint](https://greggman.github.io/webgl-lint) and added these lines

```
  const ext = glCtx.getExtension('GMAN_debug_helper');
  const tagObject = ext ? ext.tagObject.bind(ext) : () => {};
  tagObject(imgTx, 'imgTx');
  tagObject(scnBf.attachments[0], 'colorAttach');
```

Then I got this error

> error in drawElements(TRIANGLES, 6, UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0): texture WebGLTexture("colorAttach") on texture unit 0 referenced by uniform sampler2D u_texture is not renderable: texture's width(800) is not a power of 2 and height(600) is not a power of 2 but TEXTURE_WRAP_S (REPEAT) is not CLAMP_TO_EDGE and TEXTURE_WRAP_T (REPEAT) is not CLAMP_TO_EDGE.
> with WebGLProgram("*unnamed*") as current program
> with the default vertex array bound

The issue is `twgl.getContext` returns WebGL2 on Chrome/Firefox but only WebGL1 on Safari (which doesn't yet support WebGL2)

I added this [webgl-helper](https://github.com/greggman/webgl-helpers/#webgl-disable2js) to disable WebGL2 and I get the same error in Chrome.

If you just want WebGL1 always then don't use `twgl.getContext`.

Otherwise you can fix it changing the line for `twgl.createFramebufferInfo` to set WebGL1 compatible parameters

```
  scnBf = twgl.createFramebufferInfo(glCtx, [{ }],dmnsn[0],dmnsn[1]);
```

IIRC the defaults in twgl for createFramebufferInfo are `wrap: CLAMP_TO_EDGE`, `minMag: LINEAR`

```js
const dmnsn = [800, 600],
  glCtx = twgl.getContext(document.createElement("canvas")),
  imgLc =
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b6/Microsoft_logo_%281987%29.svg";
var bfInf = twgl.primitives.createXYQuadBufferInfo(glCtx),
  pgInf = twgl.createProgramInfo(glCtx, ["vs", "fs"]),
  imgTx = twgl.createTexture(glCtx, { src: imgLc }, tstSB),
  scnBf = twgl.createFramebufferInfo(glCtx, [{ }],dmnsn[0],dmnsn[1]);

function plcCv() {
  document.body.append(glCtx.canvas);
  glCtx.canvas.width = dmnsn[0];
  glCtx.canvas.height = dmnsn[1];
}
function drwTx(tx, fbi, fy) {
  twgl.bindFramebufferInfo(glCtx, fbi);
  twgl.drawObjectList(glCtx, [
    {
      programInfo: pgInf,
      bufferInfo: bfInf,
      uniforms: { u_texture: tx, u_flipy: fy }
    }
  ]);
}
function tstSB() {
  plcCv();
  drwTx(imgTx, scnBf, true);
  drwTx(scnBf.attachments[0], null, false);
}
```

```css
html{
  height:100%;
}
body{
  margin:0;
  height:100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
canvas{
  border-style:solid;
}
```

```html
<script id="vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
  
  attribute vec4 position;
  attribute vec2 texcoord;
    
  uniform bool u_flipy;
  
  varying vec2 v_texcoord;

  void main() {
    if(u_flipy) {
      v_texcoord = vec2(texcoord.x, 1.0 - texcoord.y);
    } else {
      v_texcoord = texcoord;
    }
    gl_Position = position;
  }
</script>
<script id="fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

varying vec2 v_texcoord;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main() {
  gl_FragColor=texture2D(u_texture,v_texcoord);
}
</script>
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer!  I remember now that I already knew that `twgl.getContext` defaults to WebGL2, but I forgot somehow!  I guess, because I worked with WebGL code, I assumed the context must be WebGL as well, but a WebGL2 context can deal with WebGL code of course!